# Why, if the c++ standard says that the syntax is incorrect, does g++ allow it?

Tags: c++, standards

I just read a comment that said something along the likes of:

"You should never use `void main()` you should always use  `int main()`."

Now I know the reasons for using `int main()` (so that you can check for success on return and whatnot) but I didn't know that using `void main()` was illegal.  I did some investigating and the only reason I could find not use `void main()` is because the "standard says so".

My question is:
Why, if the C++ standard says that main must return a value, does g++ allow programmers to use `void main()` as valid syntax?  Shouldn't it return an error / warning because it goes against what the standard says?

Comment: "Should" implies that it's *not* part of the standard.

Comment: Which version of g++ are you using? I know `void main()` used to work for me, but now when I try, using g++ 4.0, 4.2, and 4.4 I get `error: '::main' must return 'int'`

Comment: An implementation is explicitly allowed to add more versions of main, than the ones the standard prescribes. For example, if you compile for a device without an operating system, nobody will check the return code anyway, so `void main()` could be fine.

Comment: I'll respond to your question with another question: why IE shows correctly all the sites even when their HTML is pure crap? Or why persons comprehend one another even when the speaker makes grammatical errors? The work of a compiler is to compile, not to teach you how to write correct code (and no one ever said GCC was a fully and strictly compliant to C++ standard)

Comment: xanatos; thats actually a really stupid answer, the purpose of a compiler is to give a compile time error when something is wrong, as different from a webbrowser where the purpose is to show it as good as possible.

Comment: @Viktor Sehr: Nope. He has a point. E.g. compilers did _not_ give an error when you cast the result `dlsym` to a function type. If they did, many useful programs would not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That only means that a particular *version* of your compiler may allow it, but the later versions (which is likely to be more Standard conformant) may not allow it. So better write Standard Conformant code from the beginning!

Comment: In fact the version I use (gcc 4.5.1) disallows it for C++. If I try this for C it does compile, however if I try it with -Wall (which you really should use if you want correct code) I get a warning.

Comment: So the compiler will eventually say this is an error with future updates?

Comment: In C it's legal, see for example http://homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/legality-of-void-main.html .

Comment: Good enough for me, Thank you

Comment: @Grammin You can't be sure, but in the end you can't be sure there will be a next version of GCC. In the end I don't think how it's implemented can break anything (I mean: if it's "legal" C++ it'll compile correctly, if it isn't "legal" C++ perhaps it will compile perhaps not). You can see it as an "extension" of C++.

Answer (score 1):

According to the standard, main is indeed required to return int. But many compilers allow a return type of void since in pre-standard C++ it was allowed, and for a long time much code was written with a return type of void.

It is also worth to mention that C++ explicitly allows obission of the return statement for void:

```
int main() {
}
```

will return 0. But that is only allowed for main.

Answer (score 1):

The GNU Project has a [decent summary of their philosophy](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Non_002dGNU-Standards):

> In most cases, following published standards is convenient for users—it means that their programs or scripts will work more portably. ...
>
> But we do not follow either of these specifications rigidly, and there are specific points on which we decided not to follow them, so as to make the GNU system better for users.
>
> For instance, Standard C says that nearly all extensions to C are prohibited. How silly! GCC implements many extensions, some of which were later adopted as part of the standard. If you want these constructs to give an error message as "required" by the standard, you must specify `--pedantic`, which was implemented only so that we can say "GCC is a 100% implementation of the standard," not because there is any reason to actually use it.
>
> POSIX.2 specifies that `df` and `du` must output sizes by default in units of 512 bytes. What users want is units of 1k, so that is what we do by default. If you want the ridiculous behavior "required" by POSIX, you must set the environment variable `POSIXLY_CORRECT` (which was originally going to be named `POSIX_ME_HARDER`). ...
>
> In particular, don’t reject a new feature, or remove an old one, merely because a standard says it is "forbidden" or "deprecated."

Sometimes, GCC has removed extensions when they caused confusion like this one.  I believe this extension existed to allow old code with an incorrect `main` declaration to compile, not necessarily to encourage people writing `void main()`.  Similar to the extension that allowed pre-POSIX function declarations.  Besides, while `int main(int argc, const char** argv)` is the C-approved declaration for `main`, the C++ standard also sanctions `int main()`, and POSIX sanctions `int main(int argc, const char** argv, const char** envp)`.  There may well be other declarations that I haven't run into yet.

Comment: GNU philosophy is borderline religious.  They think they <strike>are</strike> should be the center of the universe, and therefore say stupid things like "not because there is any reason to actually use [an option that warns you about code other compilers won't accept]"

Comment: I generally agree with you.  GNU is borderline religious.  And, in fact, I think that accepting `void main()` does more to encourage bad behavior than it does to help people compiling old code.  But the question was "why does GCC allow this?" and the answer is "here's what they say about that."

Comment: I don't disagree with your answer in any way. I just wanted to point out the real world uses of pedantic which the GNU folks ignore.

Answer (score 1):

You can force the compiler to be standards compliment by using the following the build commands:

```
-ansi -pedantic -Wall
```

If you are not coding cross-platform code then `-c99` might be a better choice. Not all compilers support that.